# Selenium bypass_url failing in some scenarios

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I currently have a Python script which uses undetected-driver on Google Chrome.

In the event a URL ends with X it replaces it with Y

The issue is, if I am using a Proxy which **isn't** very very quick, the URL replacement will fail and that completely ruins my script. However, if the connection speed is quick, it will replace successfully.

So here's a scenario - I'm visting a website:
Stackoverflow.com/helpme
I click a button
The url turns to stackoverflow.com/bob
If I don't replace bob will hotdog (very quickly)
stackoverflow.com/bob will become stackoverflow.com/failure

Currently using:

```py
while not driver.current_url.endswith("bob"):
    time.sleep(0.05)
        
bypass_url = driver.current_url.replace("bob", "hotdog")
driver.get(bypass_url)
```

I have looked into waiting for elements to load before trying the URL replacement, etc etc. But I'm at a loss. Any advice is greatly appreciated!